# Is there an R function to convert this into loop so to pick data from a column?

Tags: r

I wrote an R code to translate one sentence but the requirement got expanded and now it needs to pick data from a column, one by one. Is there a way to modify the existing code to fit this ?

This is for text analysis where it uses google translate to get translated to english.

When I modify the existing code to this:

```
getParam = RawData$Translate 
translateFrom = "sp" 
translateTo = "en" 
search <- gsub(" ", "%20", getParam) 
URL <- paste("translate.google.com/…) 
page <- getURL(URL)
tree <- htmlTreeParse(page) 
body <- tree$children$html$children$body 
body_text <- body$children[[5]]$children[[1]] print(body_text)
```

It goes on loop infinite. Kindly help

Comment: You're missing a closing quote after `"translate.google.com/…`. Fix this and then let us know if the problem persists.

Comment: @Noah nope it is correct. See below;
URL <- paste("https://translate.google.com/m?hl=",translateFrom,"&sl=",translateFrom,"&tl=",translateTo,"&ie=UTF-8&prev=_m&q=",search,sep="")

Comment: That comment didn't help explain things. Look at the text you pasted in your question. Notice that there is no closing quote (`"`) after `translate.google.com/…`. The code parser sees everything after that as part of the quoted text. With no close quote, it's still waiting for you to finish the string. It's not an infinite loop; it's an unfinished piece of code.

Comment: user12003761, *that is not correct code*. If you are shortening it for the sake of the question, then there is an inherent obligation on your part to shorten it to something that is still meaningful and relatively accurate. When the sample code you provide has syntax errors in them, it is very difficult for us to (1) infer what is really supposed to be there, and (2) is this syntax omission the source of problems, or does the hidden text (removed for the question?) contain any errors?

Comment: Regardless, I think what you're asking is how to vectorize this. If this is a function called `func`, then you can replace any external instance of `func(abc)` with `Vectorize(func)(abs)` (yes, double parens), or perhaps `lapply(abc, func)` (or `sapply`).